# Number of Mappers in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapper

Let us say I have 100 files each of size 100MB and the block size is 64MB.

1) How many mappers require to process all these 100 files.

2) As we know the maximum limit for Input split size is the block size. So in our case it is going to be 64 MB. So if a mapper starts processing a input split of a file i.e 64MB how it will process the remaining 36MB. Is this mapper responsible for processing the remaining 36MB or it will be processed in some other mapper ?

Answer (score 3):

Since your block size is 64mb, So total 200 mappers will be spawned.

The same file will be processed by 2 mappers, since it's input splits are located in different location, one mapper will process the first 64MB and another mapper will process the remaining 36MB